# Getting default billing address telephone by Mage::getModel

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to get customers Primary Billing Address Telephone number in my module.

I use this code to get customer attributes, (email for example):

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('email')
```

Does `Mage::getModel('customer/customer')` return Billing Address info, too?
If yes, how can I filter it by `addAttributeToFilter()`?

Magento 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, here is the edited code for anyone having similar issue:

```
$address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('telephone', Customer Main Address Telephone)
    ->getFirstItem();
                    
$parentid = $address->getParentId();
                    
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
   ->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToFilter('Field you want to filter from Customer data', $parentid)
   ->getFirstItem();
```